# In a Select statement, add a record based on gaps in dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is some sample data.  There is a gap in the select statement results.  It would be nice to take the first record StopTime and the second record StartTime to create the missing record?  How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, consider the following query, that produces the *missing* record.

```
select 
    StopTime StartTime,
    NextStartTime StopTime, 
    datediff(minute, StopTime, NextStartTime) DurationMin
from (
    select StopTime, lead(StartTime) over(order by StartTime) NextStartTime
    from mytable
) t
where StopTime < NextStartTime
```

The subquery retrieves the next start time of each record using window function `lead()`; then, for each record that is followed by a gap, the outer query generates a record that fills it.

You can then use `union all` to bring your table, with an `order by` clause for presentation:

```
(
    select coil, StartTime, StopTime, DurationMin from mytable
    union all
    select 
        null, 
        StopTime,
        NextStartTime, 
        datediff(minute, StopTime, NextStartTime) DurationMin
    from (
        select StopTime, lead(StartTime) over(order by StartTime) NextStartTime
        from mytable
    ) t
    where StopTime < NextStartTime
)
order by StartTime
```

*[Demo on DB Fiddle with your sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=080602e1874afc0e9089f99b6eb025c5)*:

```
coil      | StartTime               | StopTime                | DurationMin
:-------- | :---------------------- | :---------------------- | ----------:
27020-100 | 2019-09-27 10:05:00.000 | 2019-09-27 18:30:00.000 |          36
null      | 2019-09-27 18:30:00.000 | 2019-09-27 20:06:00.000 |          96
27020-100 | 2019-09-27 20:06:00.000 | 2019-09-27 20:41:00.000 |          36
```

Comment: very nice... nice way to order and compare via lead() option in query.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked extremely well.  I can't begin to tell you how much this means to my project.

Comment: Thank you again @GMB, I did not understand how to "Accept" an answer!